# What is the best way to create dropdownlists in MVC 4?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, html.dropdownlistfor, html-select, viewdata, viewbag

I want to know,What is a best way to create dropdownlists in MVC 4?
With **ViewBag** or another approach?

Comment: it's not View.Bag it is ViewBag

Comment: I'd recommend you pass them with your `ViewModel`.

Comment: Hmm, I have many dropdownLists in View. I want to create them with ViewBag, but don't want to hurry, perhaps there are other ways that are gooder than viewBag

Comment: [Bind dropdownlist in mvc4 razor](http://lesson8.blogspot.com/2013/06/bind-dropdownlist-in-mvc4-razor.html)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I would argue that since the items are *variable values within your view* that they belong in the View Model. The View Model is not *necessarily* just for items coming back *out* of the View.

Model:

```
public class SomethingModel
{
    public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> DropDownItems { get; set; }
    public String MySelection { get; set; }

    public SomethingModel()
    {
        DropDownItems = new List<SelectListItem>();
    }
}
```

Controller:

```
public ActionResult DoSomething()
{
    var model = new SomethingModel();        
    model.DropDownItems.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = "MyText", Value = "1" });
    return View(model)
}
```

View:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.MySelection, Model.DropDownItems)
```

Populate this in the controller or wherever else is appropriate for the scenario.

Alternatively, for more flexibility, switch `public IEnumerable<SelectListItem>` for `public IEnumerable<MyCustomClass>` and then do:

```
@Html.DropDownFor(m => m.MySelection,
    new SelectList(Model.DropDownItems, "KeyProperty", "ValueProperty")
```

In this case, you will also, of course, have to modify your controller action to populate `model.DropDownItems` with instances of `MyCustomClass` instead.

Comment: Thank you,@Ant P.How can I get dataValueField in this example?

Comment: I want to write this  new SelectList(Model.DisplayList, "TestplanId", "Name")

Comment: @ElvinArzumanoğlu I've added some information on how you can achieve this.

Comment: It's very great example,,I think this approach(with last edit) is suitable for me.

Comment: It work fine. But now I have other problem, my dropdown doesn't select selecteditem

Comment: As long as the expression in the first argument matches the View Model property that it should populate and you pass this model back into your controller POST method, it should work. If not, it sounds like a distinct issue for a separate question.